# MySQL, displaying the specific value between row and column

Tags: mysql, sql, row, identity-column

I have a `TABLE_1`:

> emp_id | salary_step | salary_level
>     1    |     13      |     4

Now, here is TABLE_2: I'd like to query and get the value highlighted in blue. How can I do that? Thanks a lot! (salary_grade and (1-8))

see pic:
[TABLE_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKYMi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    CASE salary_level
        WHEN 1 THEN t2.`1`
        WHEN 2 THEN t2.`2`
        WHEN 3 THEN t2.`3`
        WHEN 4 THEN t2.`4`
    END AS LevelSalary
FROM TABLE_1 t1 INNER JOIN TABLE_2 t2 ON t1.salary_step = t2.salary_grade
```